# devops VSTest@2: ##[error]Could not find testhost

Tags: azure-devops, nunit, devops, mstest, azure-pipelines-yaml

We are using devops to build our .net 4.7.2 application. As part of that, we are running the unit tests which are using the nunit framework and test runner.

It has been running fine for about 18 months, but has just stopped working in the last day :(

It's using the standard template for running the tests and looks like:

```
      - task: VSTest@2
        displayName: "Running tests"
        inputs:
          testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
          testAssemblyVer2: |
              **\*test*.dll
              !**\*TestAdapter.dll
              !**\obj\**
          searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
```

However, now it is failing the step with the following logs:

> NUnit Adapter 4.2.0.0: Test execution started
> Running all tests in D:\a\1\s\Configuration.Tests\bin\Release\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll
> NUnit3TestExecutor discovered 0 of 0 NUnit test cases using Current Discovery mode, Explicit run
> Running all tests in D:\a\1\s\Configuration.Tests\bin\Release\testcentric.engine.metadata.dll
> NUnit3TestExecutor discovered 0 of 0 NUnit test cases using Current Discovery mode, Explicit run
> Running all tests in D:\a\1\s\Api.Tests\bin\Release\testcentric.engine.metadata.dll
> NUnit3TestExecutor discovered 0 of 0 NUnit test cases using Current Discovery mode, Explicit run
> Running all tests in D:\a\1\s\CommunicationTests\bin\Release\testcentric.engine.metadata.dll
> NUnit3TestExecutor discovered 0 of 0 NUnit test cases using Current Discovery mode, Explicit run
> Running all tests in D:\a\1\s\Domain.Tests\bin\Release\testcentric.engine.metadata.dll
> NUnit3TestExecutor discovered 0 of 0 NUnit test cases using Current Discovery mode, Explicit run
> Running all tests in D:\a\1\s\packages\NUnit3TestAdapter.4.2.1\build\net35\testcentric.engine.metadata.dll
> NUnit3TestExecutor discovered 0 of 0 NUnit test cases using Current Discovery mode, Explicit run
> NUnit Adapter 4.2.0.0: Test execution complete
> No test is available in D:\a\1\s\Configuration.Tests\bin\Release\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll D:\a\1\s\Configuration.Tests\bin\Release\testcentric.engine.metadata.dll D:\a\1\s\Api.Tests\bin\Release\testcentric.engine.metadata.dll D:\a\1\s\CommunicationTests\bin\Release\testcentric.engine.metadata.dll D:\a\1\s\Domain.Tests\bin\Release\testcentric.engine.metadata.dll D:\a\1\s\packages\NUnit3TestAdapter.4.2.1\build\net35\testcentric.engine.metadata.dll. Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.
> ##[error]Could not find testhost
> Results File: D:\a_temp\TestResults\VssAdministrator_WIN-FVJ4KUK6IFI_2022-08-18_12_38_44.trx
> ##[error]Test Run Aborted.
> Total tests: Unknown
> Passed: 110
> Total time: 16.7203 Seconds
> Vstest.console.exe exited with code 1.
> **************** Completed test execution *********************
> Test results files: D:\a_temp\TestResults\VssAdministrator_WIN-FVJ4KUK6IFI_2022-08-18_12_38_44.trx
> Created test run: 1080
> Publishing test results: 112
> Publishing test results to test run '1080'.
> TestResults To Publish 112, Test run id:1080
> Test results publishing 112, remaining: 0. Test run id: 1080
> Published test results: 112
> Publishing Attachments: 1
> Execution Result Code 1 is non zero, checking for failed results
> Completed TestExecution Model...
> ##[warning]Vstest failed with error. Check logs for failures. There might be failed tests.
> ##[error]Error: The process 'D:\a_tasks\VSTest_ef087383-ee5e-42c7-9a53-
> ab56c98420f9\2.205.0\Modules\DTAExecutionHost.exe' failed with exit code 1
> ##[error]Vstest failed with error. Check logs for failures. There might be failed tests.
> Finishing: Running tests

Looking through this log, it seems that the nunit tests have run successfully, but it might be trying to run mstests?  It is frustrating when devops gets an update and it breaks working pipelines.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have the similar situation.

The unit tests are run with xUnit.

> /TestAdapterPath:"D:\a\1\s" Starting test execution, please wait... A
> total of 36 test files matched the specified pattern.
> 2.4828
>
> ##[error]Could not find testhost
>
> Data collector 'Code Coverage' message: No code coverage data
> available. Profiler was not initialized..
> 2.0273
>
> ##[error]Could not find testhost
>
> Data collector 'Code Coverage' message: No code coverage data
> available. Profiler was not initialized..
> 2.3746
>
> ##[error]Could not find testhost
>
> Data collector 'Code Coverage' message: No code coverage data
> available. Profiler was not initialized..
> 1.992
>
> ##[error]Could not find testhost
>
> Data collector 'Code Coverage' message: No code coverage data
> available. Profiler was not initialized..
> 4.8409
> ##[error]Could not find testhost
>
> Data collector 'Code Coverage' message: No code coverage data
> available. Profiler was not initialized..
> 2.1874
> ##[error]Could not find testhost

I compared the output of the successful run and the failed run and found the different version of the test platform. If you don't specify a version, the default version will be the latest and probably a preview one. So I add something in YAML to specify a workable version.

```
- task: VisualStudioTestPlatformInstaller@1
  inputs:
    versionSelector: 'SpecificVersion'
    testPlatformVersion: '17.2.0'
- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    codeCoverageEnabled: True
    vsTestVersion: 'toolsInstaller'
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/vstest?view=azure-devops
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/vstest-platform-tool-installer?view=azure-devops

Comment: Same problem here, and this solution have solved it like a charm

Comment: Awesome, good spot. I find it interesting that MS see fit to use pre-release versions in their global pipelines (Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 17.3.0-preview-20220626-01 (x64))
Another pipeline tightly coupled to an external package version (we've had similar issues with node.js breaking changes). It's really not ideal.